# PostgreSQL sorting in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some column with few names separated by `,`. How to sort them in alphabetical order?

Example row:

```
| xxx,aaa,hhh,bbb |  1111 |  222  |
```

I want to get:

```
| aaa,bbb,hhh,xxx |  1111 |  222  |
```

Comment: Why do you have comma-separated values in a column to start with? In a database you only do this, when you want to remain oblivious to the strings' content. But then you wouldn't want to sort them. If you *are* interested in the separate parts, then you've already violated database first normal form. My advice: Either stay oblivious in your database and care about the parts in an app outside the db, or fix the datamodel.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you found on the Internet or stackoverflow to help you with this? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: That's a horrible data model to begin with. Do you have any chance to fix that before you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a function to do that:

```
create function sort_csv(p_input text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(u.element, ',' order by u.element)
  from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, ',')) as u(element);
$$
language sql;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select sort_csv(csv_column), other_column
from badly_designed_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function is much cleaner, but if you cannot create objects, then this will work:

```
select array_agg(value order by value) as stuff, b.col2, b.col3
  from bad_idea b
       cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(stuff, ',') as s(value)
 group by b.col2, b.col3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=30e6e9dc3a282854f6a96fa5ac09e596)*